# JavaScript multistring if function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create 4 galleries from a code that was originally only meant for one. I'll admit I know next to nothing about JavaScript being a self-taught beginner. The issue I'm having is that when I add more than 'photos' to the string all 4 galleries quit working. I have no doubt it is an easy syntax fix but I haven't been able to find it, perhaps I don't even know enough to do a proper search but I hope someone here can help.

```
function showPanel(el){
    $('section').slideUp('fast');
    $('section#'+el).slideDown(1500);

    if (el == 'photos' && 'graphics' && 'web' && 'books') {
        $('a.works').fancybox({'titlePosition' : 'inside'});
        $('a.works.iframe').fancybox({ 'type' : 'iframe', 'titlePosition'   : 'inside'})

        $('#da-thumbs > article').hoverdir();

        $('#filter a').on('click', function(){
            $('#filter a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });


        filter();

    } else if(el == 'about') {

        $('.about .avatar').remove();
        $('.home .avatar').clone().appendTo('.about #avatar');

        $('.chart').easyPieChart({
            animate : 500,

            // ----------------------------
            // Custom your chart color here
            // ----------------------------

            barColor : '#eb5b5e',
            size : 110
        });
    } else if(el == 'contact') {
        $('.gmap').mobileGmap();
    }

}
```

Comment: For starters, you will want to use OR instead of AND

Comment: For the `&&` and `||` operators you need full expressions: `if(condition1 && condition2 && ...)` It's checking is `el == 'photos'` true, then is just the string `'graphics'` also true, and so on. Just a string is always true. You will want to use `||` and make sure you state `e1` each time `el == 'photos' || el == 'graphics' || ...'`.

Comment: I have tried all of your suggestions but it still does not seem to be working. Thank you all so very much for all of your help!

Answer (score 3):

Use a switch statement. In my option, its easier to read.

```
switch (el) {
   case 'photos':
   case 'graphics':
   case 'web':
   case 'books':
     //do stuff
     break;
   case 'about':
     //do stuff
     break;
   case 'contact':
     //do stuff
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In an `if else` block you need to pass a `bool` value. Otherwise it won't work. So, when you pass a value to it. It must be like this

```
 if (el == 'photos' && 'graphics' && 'web' && 'books') {
```

This means, that if the `el` variable is equal to photos and if graphics, now the compiler won't understand what you're trying to tell it. `String != Bool`.

Change the condition to this

```
 if (el == 'photos' && el == 'graphics' && el == 'web' && el == 'books') {
```

This would change each condition to a bool (true or false) and then it would execute the code block. If `el` is equal to photos graphics web and books.

However, a variable can't hold 4 values.

So you can write it as

```
 if (el == 'photos' || el == 'graphics' || el == 'web' || el == 'books') {
```

It would check if `el` has any of the value among the ones mentioned.

Comment: That `if` statement is contradictory and will always be `false`. Probably not what the user wants.

Comment: @Juhana I was writing the very same thing this time! :) See my answer and Platinum, I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if ((el == 'photos') || (el == 'graphics') || (el == 'web') || (el == 'books')) {
```